# Is it possible to unit test this Go function that uses the AWS SDK without changing the parameters?

Tags: amazon-web-services, unit-testing, go, mocking

I am new to Go and have written a function that uses the AWS Secrets Manager to fetch a secret:

```
//Helper function to get secret from AWS Secret Manager
func getAWSSecrets() (secretMap map[string]string, err error) {
    // Create new AWS session in order to get db info from SecretsManager
    sess, err := session.NewSession()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    // Create a new instance of the SecretsManager client with session
    svc := secretsmanager.New(sess)

    //Get secret config values
    req, resp := svc.GetSecretValueRequest(&secretsmanager.GetSecretValueInput{
        SecretId: aws.String("my/secret/string"),
    })

    err = req.Send()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    ...
}
```

I need to create a unit test for the function, and to do so I need to mock the AWS Secrets Manager.  I discovered a [Secrets Manager Interface that AWS was created to help with unit testing](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/secretsmanager/secretsmanageriface/).  In the example displayed, the AWS Secrets Manager is passed into the function being tested, making it easy to pass in the mock service.  Is this the only way to successfully unit test the function?  Or can the service be mocked in the function I have above?

Comment: If you're truly constrained to not change the parameters, you'll have to mock it with a global variable placeholder. This is ugly for all the reasons global variables are ugly. If you can be a bit more flexible, by making `getAWSSecrets()` a method, rather than a function, for example, you'll have a lot more attractive options.

Comment: @Flimzy do you think it would make more sense to just move the creation of the session and the Secrets Manager instance into the main function and to change the function to take the secrets manager in as a parameter like in the AWS example or to change the `getAWSSecrets()` function into a method?

Comment: If you have that flexibility, then you have the flexibility to change parameters, and thus do things right. :) What is your actual constraint that prompted you to say "without changing parameters"?

Comment: @Flimzy I can change the parameters if that's the best way to do it, it just seemed to make sense to have all the code related to the Secrets Manager wrapped in the `getAWSSecrets()` function.

Comment: Refactoring the function to accept a `SecretsManagerAPI` argument would hands down be the easiest way to make this mockable.  Since that's an interface type, mocking it out becomes trivial, and the returned struct from `secretsmanager.New()` fulfills that interface, so you can pass it into the refactored version of `getAWSSecrets()` without modification for production usage.

Comment: In cases where you really cannot change the api of a func you could take an approach like this one: https://github.com/golang/go/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=testHookServerServe&type= but in the general case, as the other commenters pointed out, just introduce a parameter or make the func a method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the comments say, make the function call a method, and take advantage of the interface AWS is providing.

I would create a service, like this one:

```
package service

type SecretService struct {
    AwsProvider aws.SecretsManagerAPI
}

func NewSecretService() (*SecretService, err) {
    // Create new AWS session in order to get db info from SecretsManager
    sess, err := session.NewSession()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    return &SecretService{
        AwsProvider: secretsmanager.New(sess),
    }, nil
}

func (s *SecretService) GetAWSSecrets() {
    req, resp := s.AwsProvider.GetSecretValueRequest(&secretsmanager.GetSecretValueInput{
        SecretId: aws.String("my/secret/string"),
    })

    err = req.Send()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    // More magic below ...
}
```

That way in the tests, I could pass any mock into SecretService, like this:

```
func TestSecretService_GetAWSSecrets(t *testing.T) {
  service := &service.SecretService{
    AwsProvider: <use your mock here>
  }
}
```

One caveat, I guess is that the mock has to implement all methods of SecretsManagerAPI, which I think it's a lot of work for this simple scenario... in any case you can create your own interface inside the service package with only the subset of methods you'll use, let's say you're only going to use `GetSecretValueRequest`, and `CreateSecret`:

```
package service

type SecretProvider interface {
    CreateSecret(*secretsmanager.CreateSecretInput) (*secretsmanager.CreateSecretOutput, error)
    GetSecretValueRequest(*secretsmanager.GetSecretValueInput) (*request.Request, *secretsmanager.GetSecretValueOutput)
}
```

Change the service:

```
type SecretService struct {
    AwsProvider SecretProvider
}
```

Now your mock only has to implement SecretProvider interface methods only. And of course, AWS SecretsManager implicitly impleements SecretProvider.